# Failing to import external scripts using in IronPython DLR in the browser

Tags: silverlight, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I am trying to use [IronPython in the browser](http://ironpython.net/browser/) and attempting to import external python scripts:

```
<script src="http://gestalt.ironpython.net/dlr-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
...
<script type="application/python" src="test.py" defer="true"></script>
<script type="application/python">
import test
test.Hello()
</script>
```

The import statement appears to run successfully (it will fail if test.py doesn't exist). However, it doesn't appear to load the contents of the file. test.py contains the following code:

```
document.testing1.innerHTML = 'Hello from test.py'

def Hello():
   window.Alert('Hello from test.py')
```

In fact, it doesn't appear to make any difference what is in test.py. It won't complain at syntax errors.

In the IronPython console you can access from within the browser, the same issue happens:

```
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> test.Hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  at <module> in <string>, line 1
  at <module> in <string>, line 0
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Hello'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** It works with the new IronPython 2.7 beta 1 VS2010 integration which kicks off the "Chiron" test web server, but not when I use WebMatrix. I'm wondering if it is an issue with the mime-type configured for .py files being wrong on WebMatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got it working. It was MIME types that caused the problem. I was using WebMatrix for testing. I added a web.config file with the following xml to fix the issue:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".py" mimeType="text/python" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```